# Find maximum of value in a column of one dataframe given the value constraint of two columns in another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, populate

I have a dataframe, df1 with two columns representing the start and end time of task.  I have another dataframe, df2 with two columns representing time and the stock available at that time. I want to create another column in df1 named as max_stock which has maximum value of stock values for a time range given by ST and ET of df1. For instance, first task has start time `7/11/2021 1:00` and end time `7/11/2021 2:00` so for this value of `max_stock` is maximum of values in `stock` column of df2 which is maximum of 10, 26, and 48 at time `7/11/2021 1:00`, and `7/11/2021 1:30`, and `7/11/2021 2:00`, respectively.

**df1**

```
ST              ET
7/11/2021 1:00  7/11/2021 2:00
7/11/2021 2:00  7/11/2021 3:00
7/11/2021 3:00  7/11/2021 4:00
7/11/2021 4:00  7/11/2021 5:00
7/11/2021 5:00  7/11/2021 6:00
7/11/2021 6:00  7/11/2021 7:00
7/11/2021 7:00  7/11/2021 8:00
7/11/2021 8:00  7/11/2021 9:00
7/11/2021 9:00  7/11/2021 10:00
```

**df2**

```
Time            stock
7/11/2021 1:00  10
7/11/2021 1:30  26
7/11/2021 2:00  48
7/11/2021 2:30  35
7/11/2021 3:00  32
7/11/2021 3:30  80
7/11/2021 4:00  31
7/11/2021 4:30  81
7/11/2021 5:00  65
7/11/2021 5:30  83
7/11/2021 6:00  40
7/11/2021 6:30  84
7/11/2021 7:00  41
7/11/2021 7:30  15
7/11/2021 8:00  65
7/11/2021 8:30  18
7/11/2021 9:00  80
7/11/2021 9:30  12
7/11/2021 10:00  5
```

Required df

```
ST              ET              max_stock
7/11/2021 1:00  7/11/2021 2:00  48.00
7/11/2021 2:00  7/11/2021 3:00  48.00
7/11/2021 3:00  7/11/2021 4:00  80.00
7/11/2021 4:00  7/11/2021 5:00  81.00
7/11/2021 5:00  7/11/2021 6:00  83.00
7/11/2021 6:00  7/11/2021 7:00  84.00
7/11/2021 7:00  7/11/2021 8:00  65.00
7/11/2021 8:00  7/11/2021 9:00  80.00
7/11/2021 9:00  7/11/2021 10:00 80.00
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is via [conditional_join](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/functions/#janitor.functions.conditional_join.conditional_join) from [pyjanitor](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/) to simulate greater than and less than conditions, before grouping and aggregating:

```py
# pip install pyjanitor
import pandas as pd
import janitor

(df1.conditional_join(
            df2, 
            ('ST', 'Time', '<='), 
            ('ET', 'Time', '>='))
    .groupby(['ST', 'ET'], as_index = False)
    .stock
    .max()
)
                   ST                  ET  stock
0 2021-07-11 01:00:00 2021-07-11 02:00:00     48
1 2021-07-11 02:00:00 2021-07-11 03:00:00     48
2 2021-07-11 03:00:00 2021-07-11 04:00:00     80
3 2021-07-11 04:00:00 2021-07-11 05:00:00     81
4 2021-07-11 05:00:00 2021-07-11 06:00:00     83
5 2021-07-11 06:00:00 2021-07-11 07:00:00     84
6 2021-07-11 07:00:00 2021-07-11 08:00:00     65
7 2021-07-11 08:00:00 2021-07-11 09:00:00     80
8 2021-07-11 09:00:00 2021-07-11 10:00:00     80
```

You can use a cartesian join and filter afterwards (for large dataframes, this might be memory inefficient):

```py
(df1.merge(df2, how='cross')
    .query('ST <=Time <= ET')
    .groupby(['ST', 'ET'], as_index = False)
    .stock
    .max()
)
Out[113]:
                   ST                  ET  stock
0 2021-07-11 01:00:00 2021-07-11 02:00:00     48
1 2021-07-11 02:00:00 2021-07-11 03:00:00     48
2 2021-07-11 03:00:00 2021-07-11 04:00:00     80
3 2021-07-11 04:00:00 2021-07-11 05:00:00     81
4 2021-07-11 05:00:00 2021-07-11 06:00:00     83
5 2021-07-11 06:00:00 2021-07-11 07:00:00     84
6 2021-07-11 07:00:00 2021-07-11 08:00:00     65
7 2021-07-11 08:00:00 2021-07-11 09:00:00     80
8 2021-07-11 09:00:00 2021-07-11 10:00:00     80
```

Another option is with interval index (a longer process here, since the resulting interval has overlapping values):

```py
box = pd.IntervalIndex.from_arrays(df1.ST, df1.ET, closed='both')
df1.index = box

# create temporary Series
temp = (df2.Time
           .apply(lambda x: box[box.get_loc(x)])
           .explode(ignore_index = False)
         )
temp.name = 'interval'

# lump back to main dataframe (df2)
temp = pd.concat([df2, temp], axis = 1)

# aggregate:

temp = temp.groupby('interval').stock.max()

# join back to df1 to get final output

df1.join(temp).reset_index(drop=True)

                   ST                  ET  stock
0 2021-07-11 01:00:00 2021-07-11 02:00:00     48
1 2021-07-11 02:00:00 2021-07-11 03:00:00     48
2 2021-07-11 03:00:00 2021-07-11 04:00:00     80
3 2021-07-11 04:00:00 2021-07-11 05:00:00     81
4 2021-07-11 05:00:00 2021-07-11 06:00:00     83
5 2021-07-11 06:00:00 2021-07-11 07:00:00     84
6 2021-07-11 07:00:00 2021-07-11 08:00:00     65
7 2021-07-11 08:00:00 2021-07-11 09:00:00     80
8 2021-07-11 09:00:00 2021-07-11 10:00:00     80
```

Comment: Can we achieve this without using janitor package? Only by using pandas or numpy?

Comment: sure; I'll add another option

Comment: Second code throws the following error: MergeError: No common columns to perform merge on. Merge options: left_on=None, right_on=None, left_index=False, right_index=False

Comment: what version of pandas are you on, as merge with `how='cross` does not require any column. I am on pandas 1.3.4

Comment: The version is 1.1.3.

Comment: you need at least version 1.2. Have a look at pandas docs on merge for more information

Comment: What if the time values in df1 and df2 are not same? Can still the merge operation happen?

Comment: Yes, the merge will still occur since it is a Cartesian join